# How to get the current player's participant id in Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, google-play-services, google-play-games

Using google games services, how do I get the participant id of the 'current player' using Xamarin?  In Java, it's simply

`room.getParticipantId(Games.Players.getCurrentPlayerId(mGoogleApiClient));`

But I can't find the equivalent in C# with the Xamarin google games component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where `client` is a `GoogleApiClient` that has the `GamesClass.API` added and the `GamesClass.ScopeGames` added to it:

```
if (client.IsConnected)
{
    var player = GamesClass.Players.GetCurrentPlayer(client);
    Console.WriteLine(player.PlayerId);
    Console.WriteLine(player.DisplayName);
}
```